# exclude the first string from being appended to a character

Tags: javascript, jquery

**[FIDDLE Example](http://jsfiddle.net/cHtT6/2/)**

I'm learning how to append all the data attributes from `div.query` elements to a url string: `http://web.com?get=`

With the script I can get this result:

```
"http://web.com?get=|Africa|Asia|Europe"
```

But is there any way not to have the first one coupled with "|" so that the url should be

```
"http://web.com?get=Africa|Asia|Europe"
```

I want to get that result because either `http://web.com?get=|Africa|Asia|Europe`
or `http://web.com?get=Africa|Asia|Europe|` would be invalid. Any suggestions?

JS:

```
  $( document ).ready(function() {
   $(".query").each(function() { 
     var div_terms  =  $(this).data('term'),
     source =  $('#main').data('source');
       var x = source+'|'+div_terms;
       $('#main').data('source',x);
     $('.result').html(x);
   });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="main" data-source="http://web.com?get="></div>

<div class="query" data-term="Africa"></div>
<div class="query" data-term="Asia"></div>
<div class="query" data-term="Europe"></div>

<div class="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to pull all the countries to an array and join them using the pipe character.

```
var terms = $('.query').map( function() {
    return $(this).data('term');
}).get().join('|');

var source =  $('#main').data('source');

$('.result').html( source + terms );
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cHtT6/4/)

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/cHtT6/3/

You just need to replace the first `'|'` in the resulting url with an empty character `''`.

Comment: You might want to include the code in your answer and provide the jsfiddle for demoing only, otherwise the answer might be flagged to be deleted as a link-only answer.

Comment: @Juhana got that mam!

Answer (score 0):

Make it simple use javascript **`join`** function

```
  $( document ).ready(function() {
      var terms=[];
   $(".query").each(function() { 
     var div_terms  =  $(this).data('term');
       terms.push(div_terms);
   });
      var x = $('#main').data('source')+terms.join("|");
     $('.result').html(x);
});
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/XD9au/)

Answer (score 0):

Use an if statement to check if it's the first 'data-term'. If it is then don't use the | character. Then in the else statement you just do as you've already done

Answer (score 0):

## `DEMO`

Just Check whether end is reached like this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var i=0;
   $(".query").each(function() { 
       i++;
       var div_terms  = i==$(".query").length? $(this).data('term')+"":$(this).data('term')+"|",
     source =  $('#main').data('source');
       var x = source+''+div_terms;
       $('#main').data('source',x);
     $('.result').html(x);
   });
});
```

Here when last term is reached. Automatically only `""` is appended in all other cases `"|"` is appended.